# wp_mail: Using file_get_contents to include template in message

Tags: wp-mail, template-include

I want to use a template as the message in an email which I send with wp_mail.
But I get the error: "failed to open stream: No such file or directory".

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_content_type' );

$to = 'mymailg@hotmail.com';
$subject = 'welcome';
$message = file_get_contents('email_template.html' );
$headers = "From: me<noreply@me.com>";
$mailsent = wp_mail( $to,$subject,$message,$headers );

remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_content_type' );
```

This code is inside a template-part. "email_template.html" is in the same folder as this template-part.

Comment: Have you tried `./email_template.html`?

Comment: I got "Warning: file_get_contents(./email_template.html): failed to open stream"

Comment: There should be a path associated with that error. Is it correct?

Comment: where is the template part relative to the file that's loading it? use `dirname(__FILE__)` to get the path relative to the template part and not the parent file.

Comment: I got it to work! The full path was missing, so I added file_get_contents(TEMPLATEPATH . '/email_template.html' ); Is this always required??

Answer (score -1):

```
$get_file_content = fopen(TEMPLATEPATH . '/mail/create-account-member.php', "r");   

// Lê cada uma das linhas do arquivo
while(!feof($get_file_content)) { 
   $message .= fgets($get_file_content) . "<br/>";
}
fclose($get_file_content);

wp_mail( $user_email, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit how your snippet is supposed to work? Preferably in an [edit] to your answer. Also, Spanish comments are a bit tough: Not everybody speaks that language.